# Why am I getting a "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error when loading a Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I use the code below to set the report source of the crystal report & display. I added a DataSet to the project & added a DataTable to that DataSet. The DataTable is named "my_dt" & the DataSet is named "MyDataSet". The "my_dt" DataTable has exactly 3 columns to match the "Attendance" table in my database. When I press "Start Debugging", I don't get the error & it displays a blank report. When I press "Start Without Debugging" I get this error.I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace CrystalReportWithAccess
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            my_rpt objRpt;
            // Creating object of our report.
            objRpt = new my_rpt();

            String ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\CentreDB.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=pass";

            OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);

            String Query1 = "SELECT * FROM [Attendance]";

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query1, ConnStr);

            DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

            // here my_dt is the name of the DataTable which we 
            // created in the designer view.
            adapter.Fill(Ds, "my_dt");

            if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No data Found", "CrystalReportWithAccess");
                return;
            }

            // Setting data source of our report object
            objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds);

            CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject root;
            root = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
                 objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txt_header"];
            root.Text = "Sample Report By Using Data Table!!";

            // Binding the crystalReportViewer with our report object. 
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the `Ds.Tables` `object` has any elements using:

`Ds.Tables.Count > 0`

And using that in your example:

```
if (Ds.Tables.Count > 0 && Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No data Found", "CrystalReportWithAccess");
    return;
}
```

Try checking if the `ReportObjects` has any items in it.

```
if(objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects.Count > 0){

}
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance but do I have to add a using directive to use the Ds.Tables.Length property? It says I'm missing a reference.

Comment: No, it should use `Count` not `Length`

Comment: So you're using `System.Data.DataSet` right? If so, then `Ds.Tables.Count` should NOT require any other using directive. I double checked in an example, I had no issues.

Comment: No no, what I meant was, Ds.Tables.Count worked, but I'm still getting the “Index was outside the bounds of the array” error when loading the form, just like before.

Comment: What line is it failing on then ?

Comment: That's my problem too, when I press "Start Debugging" it gives no error & loads a blank report. When I hit "Start Without Debugging" it gives an error in an unusual message box & there is a details button which shows JIT exception details. Above the error it also says "Unhandled exception has occured in your program. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error & attempt to continue.etc.."

Comment: OMG it worked when I cut off "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject root;
            root = (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
                 objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txt_header"];
            root.Text = "Sample Report By Using Data Table!!";" I have no idea why though. If you figure it out please teach me as well. Thank you loads for your support @Gabe

Comment: Then you need to check if the ReportObjects has items in it. check my updated answer.